# Can "con" be a good translation for "from" (in this case)?

Tags: traducción, gramática, preposiciones

I know this is ok:

> A podcast about topics you care about **from** physicians you trust.

…translated into…

> Un podcast sobre temas que le interesan **con** médicos en los que confía.

But is this (below) also ok?

> Podcasts **con** médicos en los que confía <sub>Podcasts **from** physicians you trust</sub>

For clarification, the podcast *is* held by someone and invites physicians. It is produced by a health care system's marketing department. A large variety of physicians who work for the health care system are the guests on the podcast. The physicians are interviewed by a radio DJ.

Answer (score 1):

**"Podcasts from physicians you trust"**

(Podcasts featuring a variety of physicians you trust—and are already familiar with)

=

**"Podcasts con sus médicos de confianza"**

Comment: Gracias a @Nicoli por todo lo asistencia.

Comment: Gracias a @Gaviota por todo lo asistencia.

Comment: note that users are not notified of comments written under a post they have not interacted with (detailed info [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/643262)). If your goal is to give credit to the sources of your answer, I suggest to edit that into the answer itself. If your goal is just to thank users for their help, make sure to add the comments on posts that they have interacted with (i.e., posts they have authored, or commented on, or edited). To avoid surprises, note also that thank-you comments will be deleted after a while as "no longer needed".

Answer (score 0):

Las dos son correctas.

Aunque yo lo traduciría:

```
Un podcast sobre temas que le interesan con médicos en los que puede confiar.
```

Se escucha más natural.

Comment: Gracias por tu taducción. Yo intiendo la distinción que tu eres haciendo.
Pero las personas que leerán este anuncio ya están familiarizadas con los médicos, porque se trata de un anuncio local sobre un podcast con médicos locales. La audiencia está familiarizada con estos médicos.
Mi pregunta principal es con respecto a esta traducción:
¿Esta bien? "Podcasts con médicos en los que confía" = "Podcasts from physicians you trust"

Comment: @wstn Si la audiencia ya conoce a los médicos, creo que suena bastante más natural decir "con sus médicos de confianza". En todo caso, si, "con" sería la preposición a usar.

Comment: @Gaviota "con sus médicos de confianza" es muy bueno. Gracias.